# PHP Snappy (wkhtmltopdf (webkit pdf generator)) not liking my codeigniter pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using a PHP wrapper for [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) called [Snappy](https://github.com/knplabs/snappy). It works brilliantly on any url except for my local codeigniter generated pages. I have tried with index.php, without, with .html as a url suffix, etc. It will read a html file from the same local web directory as codeigniter, but not codeigniter's URLs (not even index.php). I am a little stumped.

- I have removed anything possibly causing a 403 from .htaccess
- there is no robots.txt
- [pyrocms](http://demo.pyrocms.com) works with it (and it is powered by CI)

Comment: Are you processing prepared html or passing in a URL?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using and the response you are getting?

Comment: I tried using wkhtmltopdf from the command line and it gives me the same thing. It just generates a blank 0 byte pdf file. It seems to only be on this CI install. I have tried sending it directly to index.php with nothing passed and I have tried other urls. Anything CI generated on my local machine it will not touch.

Edit: it gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: turns out wkhtmltopdf really doesn't like LESS CSS's `rel="stylesheet/less"` in `<head>`